# Looping over JSON (Adding HTML)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to loop over a JSON output from PHP and assign a list item to each index.

Im having two separate issues.

- The encode is adding weird slashes and quotes when they are not needed.
- I get a type error (not valid argument) when parsing the JSON string even when set from a test php array.

**PHP**

```
$data= json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo json_encode($data);
```

**JSON**

```
"[
    {\"id\":\"1\",\"user_id\":\"1\",\"message\":\"MSG 1\"},
    {\"id\":\"2\",\"user_id\":\"1\",\"message\":\"MSG 2\"},
    {\"id\":\"3\",\"user_id\":\"1\",\"message\":\"MSG 3 \"},
]"
```

**jQuery**

```
  $.ajax({ url: 'chat.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    error: function(statusCode, errorThrown) {
                updateError(statusCode, errorThrown);
            },
    success: function(data){

         $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                    $('<li data-msgid="'+data.id+'">' + data.user_id + '::' + data.message + '</li>').appendTo('#chat_area');
                 });
            });

        }
```

});

Im using ajax call rather than json as I will eventually be passing data in this same function.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The backslashes are needed to escape the double quotes since JSON uses double quotes to contain strings. You can replace them if you need but it sounds to me that this is how the string is being inserted into your database

Comment: The strings do not contain the quotes in the database. Other json calls are outputting properly, however, they are single indexes in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding twice:

```
$data= json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo json_encode($data);
```

Remove the first one and only encode the final data:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
...
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: that fixed the slash issue, however now its returning undefined on the printed list element. Its getting the current results, just not printing them correctly.

Comment: @Ray Check your variables in the inner loop, at the very least `data.id` would not exist as it would be `data[0].id`, `data[1].id`, etc. You probably want the `v` value instead. Do a `console.log()` of the variables in the inner loop and then use what you need.

Comment: @Ray By the way, you probably only want one `.each()` loop: The outer loop using the syntax of the inner loop you have now to access the variables directly.

Comment: @jereon if I remove the first loop I only have access to the first element and not able to use the v var since there is more than one "key" in my array. This is for a chat room so there will be multiple items in the array coming it a time. The PHP uses long polling (comet) but still might return more than one item. How would i make this work.

Comment: @Ray It would seem you only need one loop `$.each(data, function(k, v) {` and then you could access `v.id`, etc.